# socket io send data to newly connected client

Tags: sockets, socket.io

as everybody knows, socket.emit('event', data); will send data to all connected clients, but what how can I send it to the client who have just connected, example

client A is already connected .
client B is already connected .
client C has just connected, and I want to send him, and only him, the 'welcome' event.

how cant I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer , in socket io Docs. Here it is :

io.to(socket.id).emit('welcome', data);